# Breaking RSA: how to compute p and q efficiently from modulus given that the public exponent e=3 is fixed?

Tags: java, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've the following considerations implementing RSA cryptography in Java:

Suppose I choose e = 3 as the public exponent. Then the prime factors p and q of the modulus n must satisfy that gcd(p-1,3)=gcd(q-1,3)=1.

I use the BigInteger Java class to compute the primes p and q (probably). However most times the relation above is not satisfied.

Instead of just computing new primes using BigInteger.probablePrime(length, rmd) what could I do to efficiently find primes p and q (satisfying the relation above) given that the public exponent e=3 is fixed ?

Comment: Imho you should ask this question at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you want to break it efficiently from programming point of view, you should be using C/C++ instead of Java.